# Translation class for plugin custom exception message

Tags: c#, dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, language-translation

I want to create an class which translates my plugin custom exception messages.

I was able to achieve this for javascript with the below code :

```
  LocalizedLabels: {
    AlertMessages: {
     EmaiTemplateInvitation: {
            '1033': 'Please select an Email Template for invitations and try again.',
            '1031': 'Bitte wählen Sie eine E-Mail-Vorlage für Einladungen aus und versuchen Sie es erneut.'
        },
        TypeForecastInfo: {
            '1033': 'Please type Forecast information.',
            '1031': 'Please type Forecast information.'
        }
    },    
 // call by
 Alert.show(LocalizedLabels.AlertMessages.EmaiTemplateInvitation[Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid()], null, null, "WARNING", 500, 200);
```

I want something similar for csharp. Thankyou

Comment: So basically you want to pass int code and want string for that code in return?

Comment: no, lets say i have an exception : throw new Exception("something went wrong")
now i want a class , which holds translation for "something went wrong" and i could call it like : throw new Exception(Class.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG) 
where it selects the text based on current user logged in language, as above in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is number of methods. Here is how to determine user language:

```
int GetUserLanguageCode(IPluginExecutionContext context) 
{
  var userSettingsQuery = new QueryExpression("usersettings");
  userSettingsQuery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("uilanguageid", "systemuserid");
  userSettingsQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("systemuserid", 
    ConditionOperator.Equal, 
    context.InitiatingUserId);
  var userSettings = this.orgService.RetrieveMultiple(userSettingsQuery);

  return (int)userSettings.Entities[0]["uilanguageid"];
}
```

Next thing is you need to store localization somewhere. Options are:

1) Static dictionary (simple, but gross - since you're pouting code with static text content)

2) Embedded resources (if you're ok to ship localization always along with your plugin code)

3) Declaring separate web resource in CRM (say in xml or json format), load it dynamically (in case you need to change localization separate from your plugin release

Then when you need to throw an exception you go just like:

```
int languageCode = GetUserLanguageCode(context);
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(GetResources(languageCode, "TypeForecastInfo"));
```

How to read embedded resources (just a sample, in real life you probably want to cache them in-memory):

```
public string GetResources(int languageCode, string key)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
    using (var stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"Namespace.{languageCode}.json"))
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            var map = (Dictionary<string, string>)serializer.ReadObject(stream );
            string value;
            if (map.TryGetValue(key, out value)) 
            {
               return value;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And say `1033.json`

```
{
   "TypeForecastInfo": "Foobar"
}
```

Comment: Hello, I know all the possibilities, and how to get the user language.
I want to use Embedded resources but in resources, I am unable to make such function which will work Exception(lcid,"message").
Can you help me with that? , I can use two resources one for English and one for German and use and if before calling exception but I dont want to use and do something like you wrote.

Comment: can you give me the implementation of this function :
GetResources(languageCode, "TypeForecastInfo")

Comment: Thanks to its a good answer but I was asking about resource class using .resx files.
i made two resx files , strings.resx and strings.en.resx ,
and i use
  'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(Properties.strings.Hello);

but it awalys takes the orignal value and not the translated.